# Who or what is Milton?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Who or what is Milton and why he put mountains in hell? The name appears in the text for the first time and once in the whole story.

> When the liquor went to his head he would lie down on his bed and
>   stare out of the window until he went to sleep. He drank alone and in
>   solitude not for pleasure or good cheer, but to forget the awful
>   loneliness and level of the Divide. **Milton** made a sad blunder when he
>   put mountains in hell. Mountains postulate faith and aspiration. All
>   mountain peoples are religious. It was the cities of the plains that,
>   because of their utter lack of spirituality and the mad caprice of
>   their vice, were cursed of God.

On the Divide
by Willa Cather

Comment: It's probably a reference to the English poet [John Milton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Milton) and his late-1600s biblical epic poem [Paradise Lost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradise_Lost). Maybe someone who has read it (I haven't) can confirm this.

Comment: Paradise Lost has been translated into at least 57 languages. What makes this reference specific to learning English? Wouldn't you have the same question if the passage were translated into your native language?

Comment: @Barmar The asker has no way of knowing whether or not the phrase “Milton made a blunder” is specific to the English language somehow. I think it’s completely appropriate to ask the question here.

Comment: @Tanner Swett: Yes, even though it's more a question about English literature than the language itself.  It's the same as if some other author had inserted a reference to Chaucer, Shakespeare, or Tolkien.

Comment: @TannerSwett I don't know if I'd say "no way". A Google search for "milton mountains hell" returns almost exclusively results for Paradise Lost on the first page.

Comment: @jamesqf I don't know this site well enough to know whether it's on-topic here or not, but this question would certainly fit well at [literature.se] SE, being clearly *about* one book (where this passage is quoted from) and perhaps-not-so-clearly a reference to another.

Comment: @Randal'Thor absolutely true, but IMO Milton (along with e.g. Donne, Gray, Walter de la Mare, Shakspear and Sydney) are all people who've "entered the language" and people learning English will encounter them (and not understand the reference immediately). I think a select list of author-references should be allowed here for just that reason. I haven't checked, there might be a [meta] question.

Comment: ^^ and that bloke what wrote *the Rime of the Ancient Mariner*

Comment: @WillCrawford [Steve Harris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Harris_(musician)) you mean? :-D

Comment: @spikyjt thought that one was Bruce? He was the history buff, at least.

Comment: @WillCrawford yeah that was my first thought, so I had to look it up to check! It was definitely Steve.

Comment: @spikyjt  [adds Steve Taylor Coleridge to his list of essential English poets]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

John Milton was an important poet in the 17th century. He is most well known for a long epic poem called *Paradise Lost* which describes the creation of heaven and hell and the story of the Garden of Eden.

In Milton's description of Hell it is a rocky place with mountains, though these are not particularly important to the poem. Satan builds his palace on a mountain in hell, in imitation of God in Heaven, and summons all the devils to come to hear his wicked plan to tempt man into sin.

> At length into the limits of the North
>   They came, and *Satan* to his Royal seat
>   High on a Hill, far blazing, as a Mount
>   Rais’d on a Mount, with Pyramids and Towrs
>   From Diamond Quarries hew’n, & Rocks of Gold,
>   The Palace of great *Lucifer*, (so call
>   That Structure in the Dialect of men
>   Interpreted) which not long after, hee
>   Affecting all equality with God,
>   In imitation of that Mount whereon
>   *Messiah* was declar’d in sight of Heav’n,
>   The Mountain of the Congregation call’d;
>   For thither he assembl’d all his Train,
>   Pretending so commanded to consult
>   About the great reception of thir King,
>   Thither to come, and with calumnious Art
>   Of counterfeted truth thus held thir ears.